# Garmin GLO Accuracy in Saudi Arabia

Tags: gps, garmin, saudi-arabia

How accurate is the Garmin GLO in Saudi Arabia. I know they mention a 3m accuracy but is it achievable in Saudi Arabia. And is there a way to increase this accuracy. I require it to be around 0.5-1m. Perhaps a way to use the GLO device in a differential gps setup.

Comment: The GLO is still a consumer grade unit. For that kind of accuracy you need to get into survey grade units. It will not have differential capabilities. A couple of articles that may interest you: http://forums.gpsreview.net/discussion/29136/recommendation-for-gps-positional-and-differential-accuracy which also links to http://gpstracklog.com/2013/04/garmin-glo-review.html

Answer (score 2):

The accuracy of a GPS device is no different in Saudi Arabia than anywhere else in the world. Perhaps the availability of augmentation systems such as WAAS in the U.S. or EGNOS in Europe can enhance the accuracy to a certain extent. But if the manufacturer states that the device can achieve a 3m accuracy then it's probably what you will get 90 or 95% of the time.

If your requirements are for 0.5 to 1m accuracy then this is not the right device for you.